# How is helper 'andThen' in ember is different than traditional 'then'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

In the code below, I can use `then` instead of `andThen` and I see everything is running fine. So, what makes andThen special?

```
test('Clicked on the About page /about', function(assert) {
    visit('/')
    .click('a:contains("About")')
    .then(function(){
        assert.equal(currentURL(), '/about', 'SHould Navigate to about')
    })
});

test('Clicked on the About page /about', function(assert) {
    visit('/')
    .click('a:contains("About")')
    .andThen(function(){
        assert.equal(currentURL(), '/about', 'SHould Navigate to about')
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then` relates to waiting for a promise to finish loading. `andThen` waits for Ember’s runloop to finish before calling code inside.

Also, in newer style tests in Ember, the test helpers (click, fillIn, etc) all return promises and we no longer need to use `andThen`